# Visual Studio gives an error for returning unassigned bool

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My code looks something like this:

```cs
bool r;

for (int i = 0; i < arg.Length; i++)
{
    r = arg[i].SomethingThatReturnsBool();
}

return r;
```

For some reason, the `r` in `return r` has a red underline that says that `r` is unassigned. Does anyone know VS might think that?

Comment: If `arg.Length == 0` then `r` never get assigned. Default `r` to some value.

Comment: @loocid that’s an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 1):

Static analysis is saving you from a future mistake, obviously `length` can be 0 in which case what should this method return?

The simple solution is to just initialise something

```
bool r = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `arg` array might one day have a zero length so the body of the loop will never run and r is never assigned a value

Assign r a suitable value when declaring it, whatever value you would want it to have if arg were zero length. If you know arg will never ever have zero length it doesn’t matter what you choose (but don’t expect that the compiler will be able to deduce that arg will always have a nonzero length; some things only humans “know”.. (and getting it wrong is where bugs come from ;) ))

Answer (score 0):

You need to set value of r to false first.

```
bool r = false;
static object myLock = new object();
lock(myLock)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < arg.Length; i++)
     {
          r = arg[i].SomethingThatReturnsBool();
     }
}

return r;
```

Comment: umm, and why are we locking this, and how is it relevant to the problem?

Comment: lock for loop is a good idea. It is possible that multiple request comes at the same time